# referencing razor variables in jQuery/javascript

Tags: jquery, razor

How do I access the value of a variable set in razor from jQuery? In the code below, I'm expecting "admin" but am getting "object Object" instead. Something fundamental I'm missing.

[image: code]

Alert:
[image: alert]

Answer (score 1):

Never use `alert(object)` to try to debug.   Use

```
console.log("_area:", "@_area", $("@_area").length)
```

Objects always appears as `[Object object]` when coerced to a string

(either via `alert` or via `"" + obj`)

In your case, `@_area = "admin"` so this will output in the html/javascript as:

```
$("admin")
```

which isn't a valid selector, so should be:
`$("#@_area")`

Also note that if you output a jquery object `$("bad_selector")` - it's still a jquery object, so use `$("bad_selector").length` to determine if it's working.

You can also view the *rendered* html to see what your Razor is generating, sometimes this will make the answer obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$('...')` - is JQuery object. Check this out: `alert("_area: " + '@_area')`

Comment: Or just `alert('_area: @_area')`